# How to ensure that line thickness is kept consistent in a Grease Pencil object when scaling it up using a lattice

Tags: armature, transforms, grease-pencil, lattice

I've noticed that, when a GreasePencil object is attached to a Lattice via the "Lattice" modifier, and the Lattice is scaled up by using the "Armature" attached to a bone that is scaled up, the drawing becomes larger while the lines do not become thicker. This isn't like the usual scaling behavior, where the lines do become thicker in response.

[image: left image has thinner lines than the right]

Is there a way to ensure that scaling occurs normally (i.e. lines thicken) when using lattices?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is due to the nature of the Lattice modifier and the GP objects: the lattice move vertices, when you scale the lattice you're not scaling the drawings, you're moving their vertices closer to each other but their stroke thickness remains unchanged.

A workaround is to add a thickness modifier, select in pose mode an appropriate bone (maybe a Root bone if you need to scale the whole object), right click on one of its scale transform values and choose "Copy as new driver". Then hover over the modifier  "Thickness value" parameter, right click and choose "Paste as new driver".

[image]

Comment: Works like a charm! Thank you!